# More efficient processing of many XYZ tiles into a merged response

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, xyz

I've built a mobile mapping device for my Search & Rescue group using a Raspberry Pi (3b+) and its primary purpose is to serve a cache of XYZ tiles via its web server, over its WiFi network. The device is powered using a vehicle's 12V power outlet. Our SAR group uses a number of mapping applications that understand the XYZ tile format. We are regularly outside cell service and satellite internet is problematic, so the goal is to take data with us when we head out on a call.

As a bonus feature I've added the ability to export a georeferenced PDF of any area, with the PDFs content built from the relevant XYZ tiles using GDAL. This works OK but it's slow and I'm wondering if I can remove any of the more expensive steps from the transformation.

The current steps are:

1. identify all XYZ tiles at a given zoom level that intersect the caller's lat/long bounding box (this is fast)
2. call GDAL Transform for every XYZ tile, converting it to a .tif with its `outputBounds` set to the correct bounding box. This can mean several thousand calls to Transform and this part is very slow
3. call GDAL Warp to merge all Transformed .tif tiles into a single .tif (relying on the newly-added georeferencing data from step 2)
4. call GDAL Transform to convert the merged .tif to a PDF

I'm already using the Pi's "overlay file system", which I believe writes exclusively to memory / swap space - it's effectively a temporary file system where all changes are lost on reboot - and this made the export significantly faster. This also helps to mitigate the risk of storage corruption as the power supply is regularly interrupted.

It seems like there should be a way to remove step 2, where hundreds or thousands of tiles are individually georeferenced before being merged, but this would require some way of telling GDAL a) the overall bounds of the combined XYZ tiles and b) the order in which the XYZ tiles should be assembled, because without georeferencing we don't know where each tile belongs in the world.

Can anyone suggest a way to make this process more efficient?

Comment: Is your XYZ regular (raster) or irregular (points)? A regular XYZ can be established as a BIL file, taking the origin and cell size from the header to align world coordinates to cells. It sounds like you're projecting on the fly, try to avoid doing that, if you could pin your application down to a UTM zone or use Google Web Mercator for input/output you would save yourself several thousand cycles.

Comment: The GDAL TMS minidriver that is documented together with the WMS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html is almost what you'd need because it knows which x/y/z tiles to read and where they belong without georeferencing them individually. I fear that it is missing the ability to read from a file cache but if you are running http server anyway on your Pi it should be not any problem. For total offline use you could save the tiles into MBTiles or GeoPackage database instead of the  directory structure.

Comment: I gave a [talk](https://www.ianturton.com/talks/pirates-foss4g/index.html) ([video](https://vimeo.com/248675454)) on using GeoServer and MapProxy to do this - GeoServer would allow you to download a PDF directly as a WMS output

Comment: @IanTurton thanks but GeoServer and its associated Java baggage is likely far too much for the Pi - I only have 1GB RAM to work with and I want to keep as much as possible free for the temp file system and the device's web server (which is its primary purpose). GeoServer and mapproxy for a "bonus feature" on a low-spec device seems overkill

Comment: @MichaelStimson thanks for your input. The XYZ tile system conforms to the pseudo-standard system used in Google Maps, OpenLayers, Leaflet etc. - it's already in Web Mercator, but the individual tiles are "georeferenced" by directory and file name index according to the XYZ system's conventions. The georeferencing step (step 2) is not reprojection per se, but creating a duplicate file that has georeferencing metadata attached to it beyond that directory and file name index. I'm just telling the tile where it is so that it can tell GDAL.

Comment: @user30184 thanks, I think this looks like my best option and I had not seen this before. I should be able to point GDAL to my web server and save a bunch of processing. As for your MBTiles / GeoPackage suggestion I don't think this is my best option. The applications that will use this device expect to retrieve tiles from a URL `http://domain/tileset/z/x/y.png`. If I store the tiles in some kind of package then my web server needs to know how to unpack that package. For simplicity I can just store each file individually on disk. I currently have ~15m tiles without noticeable perf. issues

Comment: Actually those experiments were on a pi3

Comment: @user30184 can you post your suggestion as an answer? I got this approach working and I'm very happy with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL can read XYZ tiles from a http server directly with the GDAL TMS minidriver that is documented together with the WMS driver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html.

TMS minidriver reads the configuration of the tile service from a small XML file that defines the tiling schema. By the schema the driver knows the georeferencing of the tiles and URLs to access them. Therefore there is no need to georeference the tiles individually.

An example about TMS configuration file:

```
GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="TMS">
        <ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <DataWindow>
        <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
        <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
        <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
        <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
        <TileLevel>18</TileLevel>
        <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
        <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
        <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
    </DataWindow>
    <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
    <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
    <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
    <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
    <!--
    <UserAgent>Please add a specific user agent text, to avoid the default one being used, and potentially blocked by OSM servers in case a too big usage of it would be seen</UserAgent>
    -->
```